# Resharper support for NUnit 3.0 alpha

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, resharper

Is there any way to inject support into Resharper for NUnit 3.0 alpha? I don't see a Resharper extension for that version of NUnit and the NUnit page says that the 2.x version runner won't run 3.x tests properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, this support is not yet available. The package information for NUnit 3.0.0.0-alpha-4(Pre-release) mentions:

> This package includes the NUnit 3.0 framework assembly, which is
>   referenced by your tests. You will need to install version 3.0 of the
>   nunit-console program or a third-party runner that supports NUnit 3.0
>   in order to execute tests. Runners intended for use with NUnit 2.x
>   will not run 3.0 tests correctly

However, when you look closely to the [NUnit Release Notes page](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=releaseNotes&r=3.0) for the latest version, you may read the following:

> Engine
>
> **A driver is now included, which allows running NUnit 2.x tests under
>   NUnit 3.0.**
>   ...

So when you use the latest alpha pre-release, you might have succes. Otherwise you'll have to wait till the official runners come out.